# how do i bring a viewcontroller from the navigation controller to the front

Tags: swift

Can i bring a specific ViewController from my Navigation Controller's stack to the front without reloading it or closing any of the others first? Pretty much like `popToViewController` but without removing the top ones

Answer (score 0):

Generally remove from `viewControllers` and push it again

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())
if nav.viewControllers.count > 1 {
    let last = nav.viewControllers.removeLast()
    nav.pushViewController(last, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `self.navigationController?.viewControllers` to get all the navigation stack controllers and change the position as you want.

Here in the example, First I find the Controller from the navigation stack and move at last.

```
if let navigationController = self.navigationController,
   let indexForController = navigationController.viewControllers.firstIndex(where: {$0 is YourControllerName}) {
    let removedController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: indexForController)
    self.navigationController?.viewControllers.append(removedController!)
}
```